# How to determine the number of all the Sylow subgroups of $A_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, sylow-theory

**Question:** How to determine the number of all the Sylow subgroups of $A_8$.

I'm trying to use some Sylow Theorems (especially the $3^{rd}$ Sylow theoreom).

**My approach:** (I'm not sure, but so far I've got)

The $2-$Sylow subgroups are self normalizing, so there are $315$ of them.

There are $280$ ,$3-$Sylow subgroups.

Not sure about $5$ and $7$ Sylow subgroups yet, also not sure about what I did with $2$ and $3$.

Should I also calculate all the $p$ Sylow subgroups as well?

Also, I know that $GL(2,4) \cong A_8$, for every class of $GL(2,4)$ I've calculated the size of the class and the order of the elements, and found all the representatives for all the conjugacy classes in that group, I believe it also could help me somehow.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156352/on-the-sylow-subgroup-of-alternating-groups), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795732/this-is-about-sylow-subgroups-of-alternating-group-a-n-multiple-choice/795770).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you, except for finding the number of $p$ Sylow subgroups with the formula in one of the posts, it didn't help me further to calculate $5$ and $7$ sylow subgroups, any further insights would be appreciated (:

Comment: Did you have a look at the article **On the Sylow Subgroups of the Symmetric and Alternating Groups** by L. Weisner from the first link?